# How to insert a tab character in a DataGridView Header in order to vertically align the text?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, string-formatting

I am setting the TopLefftHeaderCell text with a string containing tabs character in order to vertically align the values. The tab characters are not displayed.

Following is my code:

```
datagridview.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = string.Format(
    "Name:\t{1}{0}Age:\t{2}{0}", Environment.NewLine, name, age);
```

I am getting the following result:

```
// Name: John Smith
// Age: 50
```

How can I get the following result so John Smith and 50 will be vertically left aligned:

```
// Last Name: John Smith
// Age:       50
```

Comment: Well, double tabs makes it aligned: `"Last Name:\t{1}{0}Age:\t\t{2}{0}"`

Comment: Already tried, not working

Comment: Anyways, why put so much data in one cell?

Answer (score 1):

You can count the difference between the two strings and add an amount of spaces equal to the difference with a function like this:

```
public static int SpaceDiff(string first, string second)
{
    return first.Length - second.Length;
}
```

And then use it like:

```
string str1 = "Last name: ";
string str2 = "Age: ";

string.Format( str1 + "{1}{0}" + str2 + new string(' ', SpaceDiff(str1, str2)) + "{2}{0}", Environment.NewLine, "John Smith", "50")
```

Produces the following:

```
// Last Name: John Smith
// Age:       50

// Name: John Smith
// Age:  50
```

Comment: It will not work since the text lenght can be equal however the width of each character differ and therefore the text won't be aligned properly

Comment: Or just add space to the end of `str2` until it's the same length as `str1`. You *already know their values*.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did for now